# How do I get these SVG fonts to work?

Tags: svg, fonts, coreldraw

I need to dynamically make an SVG in my web app and to do so I'm making an SVG in Corel and modifying that template file in Node.js as needed. This works except for fonts. For this project I need my text as text, not curves, because I need to modify it. I'm using Century Gothic. I was using embedded fonts, but apparently those are no longer supported by Chrome and Edge. However, if I used linked fonts the file renders improperly if the user doesn't have the font installed. In either of these error cases the browser defaults to Times New Roman. What can I do to get Century Gothic to render in all browsers in an SVG?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [web font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts). Century Gothic is not freely available, so you have to either buy a license, or use an open source alternative. [Muli](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Muli) seems to be [considered](http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/closest-font/font/century-gothic) as a good alternative. For how to use an external font provider, see [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/#article-header-id-5).